# Is invariance of a multi-linear form required for co/contra variance?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I'm reading the book: The Absolute Differential Calculus by Levi-Civita to get an idea of the history behind the development of tensor calculus.

On page 71 he states:

> An m-fold covariant is an m-fold system which is transformed in the same way as the coefficients of a multilinear form in point variables; an m-fold contravariant is one which is transformed in the same way as the coefficients of a multilinear form in dual variables.

The few pages beforehand has required the multilinear form to be invariant, so has this been incorrectly left out in the above definition?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell

*"tensors on a manifold $M$ are global objects which are invariant by definition; their components transform under coordinate change following laws called covariance & contravariance "*

*"the $m$-fold systems (pag. 65 and pag.71 in *loc.cit*.) are not invariant under change of coordinates: they transform covariantly or contravariantly because they are the **coefficients** of tensors on the manifold $M$, not tensors themselves".*

Let us clarify this point.

- General statements tensors on manifolds

Tensors on manifolds, when given locally, have coefficients with precise transformation rules under coordinate transformations: the tensor itself is *invariant*, as it is "globally" given as a section of a certain fiber bundle over the manifold $M$ under analysis: its *local* espression depends on coordinates, though.

For example, the multi-vector field (or contravariant tensor field) $X\in\Gamma(\wedge^m TM)$ is locally given by

$$X=X_{i_1,\dots,i_m}(x_1,\dots,x_n)\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i_1}}\wedge\dots\wedge\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i_m}}\in \wedge^m T_pM$$

at point $p\in M$ in local coordinates $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$; it transforms under change of coordinates $x_{\bullet}\mapsto y_{\bullet}=y_{\bullet}(x_{\bullet})$
by remembering that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_r}=\frac{\partial y_s}{\partial x_r}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_s}. $$

In summary, in coordinates $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ we have
$X=X_{i_1,\dots,i_m}(x_1,\dots,x_n)\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i_1}}\wedge\dots\wedge\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i_m}}$; in the coordinates
$(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ the tensor $X$ (it is globally invariant!) is given by
$X=\tilde{X}_{j_1,\dots,j_m}(y_1,\dots,y_n)\frac{\partial }{\partial y_{j_1}}\wedge\dots\wedge\frac{\partial }{\partial y_{j_m}}$, with
$$\tilde{X}_{j_1,\dots,j_m}(y_1,\dots,y_n)=X_{i_1,\dots,i_m}(x_1,\dots,x_n)
\frac{\partial y_{j_1}}{\partial x_{i_1}}\cdots\frac{\partial y_{j_m}}{\partial x_{i_m}}.$$

Dualizing one considers differential forms and coordinate transformations inducing

$$dy_s=\frac{d y_s }{d x_r}d x_r $$

at the level of differentials.

Comment: Is the multilinear form in the OP quote always invariant to a change in coordinates: yes or no?

Comment: This is no interrogation, so please check your tone. I will edit my answer with more details, to leave no doubt about invariance.

Comment: I was trying to help you get to answering the point of my question, it wasn't meant to be an interrogation ;) So let me put it another way: what calculation do we perform on the components of a tensor that makes it "invariant"? I suspect we create a multilinear form from its components and its dual tensor, and this is an invariant. BTW, I'm learning tensors from scratch using this book, so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: ok, no problem :) Well, your guess is going to the right direction: the global object, i.e. the tensor, is invariant by definition. Its definition uses the "section of a fiber bundle..." machinery. One uses it to express the tensor in a local expression and checks the transformation formulae of the components/coefficients. I think that learning tensors with the Levi Civita book is a difficult task: it is a great book but a bit outdated. Why don't you try with something more modern and accessible? ps: we are all ignorant!